# Local notification when background task about to expired

Tags: ios, background, uilocalnotification

Can iOS app schedule local notification when background task is about to expired?
Basically i have some server side ongoing download when app enters to background using NSOperationQueue.
What i want is to notify user by Local notification when background tasks are about to finish.So that user can bring app to foreground to keep continuing server data download
Below is code i am being using but i didnt see any local notification

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           /*TO DO
            prompt the user if they want to continue syncing through push notifications. This will get the user to essentially wake the app so that sync can continue.
             */
            // create the notification and then set it's parameters
            UILocalNotification *beginNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
            if (beginNotification) {
                beginNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
                beginNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                beginNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
                beginNotification.alertBody = @"App is about to exit .Please bring app to background to continue dowloading";
                beginNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                // this will schedule the notification to fire at the fire date
                //[app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                // this will fire the notification right away, it will still also fire at the date we set
                [application scheduleLocalNotification:beginNotification];
            }

            [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
            self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }];
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? I mean schedule local notification from background ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem with your code is `dispatch_async` call. Here's something from docs:

> **`-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`**
>   (…) The handler is called synchronously on the main thread, thus blocking the application’s suspension momentarily while the application is notified.

That means your application is suspended immediately after this expiration handler finishes. You are submitting asynchronous block on main queue and because this actualy *is* main queue (see docs), it will be executed *later*.

**Solution for this is not to call `dispatch_async`**, but instead run that code directly in this handler.

Another problem I see, is that notifying the user in expiration handler is too late and should be done before expiration (like one minute or so). You just need to periodicaly check for `backgroundTimeRemaining` and show this alert once it reaches your interval.

Answer (score 0):

Your code never gets executed, because you schedule your code to be run in the future and then you terminate your backoground task via `endBackgroundTask:`. Also, the expiration handler is called on the main thread, so you can simply put your code in there and avoid this `dispatch_async` and `performSelectorOnMainThread:` foobar.

Comment: Block handler are basically called on background thread so for any UI changes need to be explicitly implemented on main thread i.e dispatch_sync is used.

Comment: documentation says "Each call to this method must be balanced by a matching call to the endBackgroundTask: method. Apps running background tasks have a finite amount of time in which to run them. If you do not call endBackgroundTask: for each task before time expires, the system kills the application. If you provide a block object in the handler parameter, the system calls your handler before time expires to give you a chance to end the task." <br>When should i do that .Also why cant i see local notification scheduled for current time?